# capture multiple pictures per second,and name use time and frame number

Tags: c++, opencv

I use this code to detect motion and save pictures name with system time, like 2013-11-26_01:20, but only can 1 picture per second. I want to take multiple pictures name like 2013-11-26_01:20-1,2013-11-26_01:20-2 ... 2013-11-26_01:21-1,2013-11-26_01:22-2.

```
bool saveImg(Mat image, const string DIRECTORY, const string EXTENSION, const char * DIR_FORMAT, const char * FILE_FORMAT){

stringstream ss;
time_t seconds;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char TIME[80];

time (&seconds);
timeinfo = localtime (&seconds);

// convert dir...
strftime (TIME,80,DIR_FORMAT,timeinfo);
ss.str("");
ss << DIRECTORY << TIME;

if(!directoryExists(ss.str().c_str()))
    mkdir(ss.str().c_str(), 0777);

// convert image name
strftime (TIME,80,FILE_FORMAT,timeinfo);
ss.str("");
ss << DIRECTORY << TIME << EXTENSION;

// save image
return imwrite(ss.str().c_str(), image);
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

// const
const string DIR = "/home/balice/Desktop/";
const string EXT = ".jpg";
const int DELAY = 100; // mseconds

string DIR_FORMAT = "%d-%m-%Y";
string FILE_FORMAT = DIR_FORMAT + "/" + "%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S";

// create all necessary instances
CvCapture * camera = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
Mat original =  cvQueryFrame(camera);
Mat next_frame = original;
Mat current_frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
Mat prev_frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

cvtColor(current_frame, current_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvtColor(prev_frame, prev_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvtColor(next_frame, next_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);

Mat d1, d2, result;
int window = 200;
bool movement;
while (true){     
    movement = false;
    absdiff(next_frame, current_frame, d1);
    absdiff(current_frame, prev_frame, d2);
    bitwise_xor(d1, d2, result);

    int middle_y = result.rows/2;
    int middle_x = result.cols/2;

    // Center window
    threshold(result, result, 140, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    for(int i = middle_x-window; i < middle_x+window; i++)
        for(int j = middle_y-window; j < middle_y+window; j++)
            if(result.at<int>(j,i)>0)
            {
                movement = true;
                break;
            }

    if(movement==true)
        saveImg(original,DIR,EXT,DIR_FORMAT.c_str(),FILE_FORMAT.c_str());

    imshow("Motion", result);

    prev_frame = current_frame;
    current_frame = next_frame;

    // get image from webcam
    next_frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
    cvtColor(next_frame, next_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        break;
    }    
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is filenames limit. All images, taken in the same second have the same filenames. As solution I can suggest use milliseconds, or add some counter incrementing after image written to disk, and resetind every new second. You need add this counter value to filename.